# Entity Framework 4.1 POCO - many-to-many loading

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many, poco

I have the following 4 tables (simplified for this question):

---

## Company

CompanyId | Name

## Employee

EmpoyeeId | CompanyId | FirstName | LastName

## Permission

PermissionId | CompanyId | Permission

## EmployeePermission

EmployeePermissionId | PermissionId | EmployeeId

---

And the POCO as below:

```
[Table("Employee")]
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public Company Company { get; set; }
    public List<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }
}
```

I want to be able to load the company and permissions as properties of Employee. I can get the Company to load with the following code:

```
var employee = _context.Employees
            .Where(u => u.EmpoyeeId == 1234)
            .Include(u => u.Company)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Not sure how to load the collection of Permission though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make changes to the database structure to achieve that.

Your `EmployeePermission` table should contain only 2 foreign key columns. By doing so EF will manage the link table transparently and you can have `Permissions` property in `Employee` class.

Change the `Employee` class definition to make the navigational properties virtual.

```
[Table("Employee")]
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can eager load `Permissions`

```
var employee = _context.Employees
            .Where(u => u.EmpoyeeId == 1234)
            .Include(u => u.Company).Include(u => u.Permissions)
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

for many to many relationship

```
public class Employee
{

 public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Permission> Permissions { get; set; }
}

public class  Permission {

public virtual ICollection<Employee> Employee{ get; set; }
}
```

that create a new table EmployeePermission with Employee_Id and Permission_Id